# Android RelativeLayout troubles

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

I am quite new to relative layouts and I am struggling with them ;)

What I am trying to do is that:
http://pineapple.cc/plan.jpg

But what I get is that:
http://pineapple.cc/result.jpg

This is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/list_poi_image"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/list_poi_ll"
        android:background="#000000" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_poi_ll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/list_poi_name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/list_poi_date_created"
                android:text="Name"/>
             <TextView android:id="@+id/list_poi_date_created"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="Date created"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <TextView android:id="@+id/list_poi_description"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/list_poi_date_planned"
                android:text="Description"/>
             <TextView android:id="@+id/list_poi_date_planned"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="Date planned"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong ???

Thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to use RelativeLayouts to the best of there abilities, there is no need to have RelativeLayouts/LinearLayouts within other RelativeLayouts/LinearLayouts.

For examples of how to use RelativeLayouts look at:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html

In terns of what your looking for the following is what you are looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_created"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="DateCreated"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_planned"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/description"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/description"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="DatePlanned"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please note that the hard-coded Strings are in there to enable you to see the text. Ensure you remove these and use a strings.xml file.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I did not know that the relative layouts were so "powerful", now I understand better how to use them

Thank you a lot for you help !!! (the strings were used for debug)